# replace space with new line

Tags: php

I have a string thats separated by a space. I want to show every part of the string on new line that is separated by space. how can I do that.

```
base1|123|wen dsj|test base2|sa|7243|sdg  custom3|dskkjds|823|kd
```

if there is no more | after an initial pipe then the space should break the line and it   should look like this

```
base1|123|wen dsj|test 
base2|sa|7243|sdg  
custom3|dskkjds|823|kd
```

Comment: Any reason `dsj|test` isn't on its own line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty messy, yet to clean up the last empty result:

```
$string = 'base1|123|wen dsj|test base2|sa|7243|sdg custom3|dskkjds|823|kd';
preg_match_all('/(?P<line>(?:[^\\| ]*\\|{0,1})*(?: [^\\| ]*\\|[^\\| ]*(?: |\\z){0,1})*)(?: |\\z)/',$string,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Edit: Actually this is pretty horrible

Answer (score 18):

```
echo str_replace(' ',"\n",$string);
```

or

```
echo str_replace(' ',PHP_EOL,$string);
```